# Duplicate extern constant when linking static library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-linking

I wrote libraryA.

```
//classA.h
extern NSString *const ConstantString;

//classA.m
NSString *const ConstantString = @"aaa";
```

I wrote libraryB

```
//classB.m
#import <libraryA/classA.h>
```

Also *libraryA.a* added to   of libraryB -> build phase -> link binary with libraries.

Then in my main project, I need to import classA and classB together.So I added *libraryA.a* and *libraryB.a* both to main project -> build phase -> link binary with libraries.

There comes the problem when linking.It says duplicate symbol of `ConstantString`.

So, how to fix it?

Comment: You can't do this with static libraries. Have LibraryB force-include the entire LibraryA and then just link LibraryB to your other project. It's better to separate these, however. Don't have anything in LibraryA directly exposed to your project, make it lower level, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Jason's comment at very first.
I think I found the right solution after discussion with my colleagues. libraryB should not link against libraryA after compilation. Linking should be done after compiling the main project.
I removed libraryA from libraryB -> build phase -> link binary with libraries. Error never shows again.